# IAR output bin file size is 2MB, however .map file reports a size of 61.8KB being used

Tags: file, bin, iar

I'm working on a project using IAR (version 8.50.9)
when I build the project, no errors. The map file reports

```
  59'156 bytes of readonly  code memory
   2'741 bytes of readonly  data memory
  15'344 bytes of readwrite data memory
```

I can also see on the map file 61.8KB of program code and data is about right.
When I run from the debugger using an IJet Pod, it uses a .sim file as an output file, its size is about 61.8KB
However, when I build the project (after cleanAll), the output bin file size is 2MB
Any help will be appreciated
thanks

Tried different setting on the .icf file, no success

Comment: What memory ranges are available and where in them is data assigned? Also, is unused memory filled in by linker?

Comment: Keep in mind that raw binary files have no structure, so any empty areas in between used sections must be filled with dummy bytes. If this is not desirable, then use more structured output format.

Answer (score 1):

If the binary format is a real requirement for the output, the IAR ELF Tool (`ielftool`) has the `--bin-multi` option which spans the converted output to the actual used ranges.

The syntax is:

```
ielftool --bin-multi [input.elf] [output_prefix]
```

Take this discontiguous FLASH_region as an example for the linker configuration:

```
define region FLASH_region  =   mem:[from 0x8000000 size 1M]
                              | mem:[from 0x9000000 size 1M]
                              | mem:[from 0xA000000 size 512k];
/* ... */
place in FLASH_region { readonly };
```

Considering that all the three ranges were used, `ielftool --bin-multi` will convert the ELF to the corresponding segmented outputs:

```
   IAR ELF Tool V10.6.13.1289 [BUILT locally]
   Copyright 2007-2020 IAR Systems AB.

Loading input.elf
Saving binary file to output_prefix-0x8000000
Saving binary file to output_prefix-0x9000000
Saving binary file to output_prefix-0xa000000
```

each of which without the zeroed gaps between used ranges, following the application layout in the linker configuration.

*As advised by user694733 in the comments, if a single file is preferred for flashing the target, consider other formats such as Intel (`.hex`) or Motorola (`.srec`). The IAR ELF Tool can convert the `input.elf` to an output in any of these formats.*